# Angular forward slash in wildcard route

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular9

I have a URL like the following and I need to implement route handlers for it:

```
/shop/et--zubehoer-c16/zubehoer-c48/top-cases--taschen-c63/top-case-32l-rosso-passione-p64
```

That follows the logic:

```
/shop/{path}/{productname}-p{product}
```

So, `path` is a variable category structure containing even forward slashes, in this example `et--zubehoer-c16/zubehoer-c48/top-cases--taschen-c63`. `productname` would be `top-case-32l-rosso-passione` and `product` would be `64`.

This route logic is existing in a Symfony backend that I'm now replacing with Angular. Therefore, I need to implement the same logic. This is the Symfony route definition:

```
 // Product detail pages
 @Route("/{path}/{productname}-p{product}", name="shop-detail", defaults={"path"=""}, requirements={"path"=".*?", "productname"="[\w-]+", "product"="\d+"})

 // Category pages
 @Route("/{path}", name="shop-listing", defaults={"path"=""}, requirements={"path"=".*?"})
```

I would like to have two handlers for this route:

- One that handles all category pages, e.g. ``

  - `/shop/`
  - `/shop/et--zubehoer-c16/`
  - `/shop/et--zubehoer-c16/zubehoer-c48/top-cases--taschen-c63/`
- One that handles the product detail page, so pages that end with `pXXX` where `p` indicates that it's product detail page, e.g.

  - `/shop/et--zubehoer-c16/zubehoer-c48/top-cases--taschen-c63/top-case-32l-rosso-passione-p64`

The problem here is of course that the first handler has a variable amount of sub-directories. What I could imagin is to differentiate these two with the ending `p{product}`. If this exists in the URL, the product detail handler should be called otherwise the category handler.

A first attempt to use the following didn't work:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'shop',
  children: [{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () => import('product-listing').then(m => m.ProductListingModule),
  }, {
    path: '**/p:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('product-detail').then(m => m.ProductDetailModule),
  }]
}, {
  path: '**',
  component: NotFoundComponent
}];
```

Comment: how you are navigating to these routes, and what problems are you facing?

Comment: @AakashGarg It's hierarchical as you can see in the above URL examples. So, I'm starting with some category pages, and maybe at the second level I'm clicking on a product that then opens the product detail page. Since category pages have a flexible hierarchy level I don't know how to make the routing for the product detail page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma623777526433166?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Instead of using the `path` attribute in your routes, you can use the poorly documented `matcher` attribute (check it on [the docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#matcher)). You probably haven't heard of it because it's not that common. But basically you provide a function that takes the paths segments (actually, an array of `UrlSegment` => each `UrlSegment` contains a `path` attribute referring to an element of the array produced by `path.split('/')`). If the matcher function returns `null`, it means that you haven't found a match. If it returns the array of path segments, it means it's a match.

So, you can define your matcher as:

```js
// matches /shop/{path}/{productName}-p{product}
export function productMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  // The path must start with 'shop' and have more than 1 segment
  if(!url || url.length < 2 || url[0] !== 'shop') {
    return null;
  }

  // The last segment is supposedly your product
  const productSegment = url[url.length - 1].path;

  // The 'g' option (global search) is mandatory for the 
  //   regex.exec(...) below to work right
  const regex = /([a-zA-z0-9-]+)(-p)(\d+)$/g;

  // If it doesn't match the regex, it's not a product: it's a category
  if (!regex.test(productSegment)) {
    return null;
  }

  // To the regex.exec(...) function work right, you must reset the index
  //   because it was messed up by regex.test(...) function
  regex.lastIndex = 0;
  const m: string[] = regex.exec(productSegment);

  // If there are matches, m is different from null
  if (m) {
    const [whole, productName, _, product] = m;

    const category = url
      .slice(0, url.length - 1)
      .map(x => x.path)
      .join('/');

    // Return the original segments, and add some parameters
    //   to be grabbed from the paramMap.
    return {
      consumed: url,
      posParams: {
        category: new UrlSegment(category, {}),
        productName: new UrlSegment(productName, {}),
        product: new UrlSegment(product, {})
      }
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then, in your routes config:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: productMatcher,
    component: ProductComponent
  }
];
```

And in the component:

```js
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  route.paramMap.subscribe(m => {
    this.productName = m.get("productName");
    this.product = m.get("product");
    this.category = m.get("category");
  });
}
```

In a similar way, you can build a matcher for the categories. Looking at the product matcher, if among its segments we find the term `shop`, and it's not a product, it has to be a category (at least by the conditions mentioned in the question text.

```js
// matches /shop/{path}
export function categoryMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  if(!(url && url.length && url[0].path === 'shop')) {
    return null;
  }

  // Just '/shop'
  if (url.length === 1) {
    return return {
      consumed: url,
      posParams: {
        category: new UrlSegment('', {}),
      }
    };
  }

  const lastSegmentPath = url[url.length - 1].path;

  // Every category (except shop) finish with a dash followed by a
  //   letter different from "p" followed by one or more numbers
  const categoryRegex = /(-[a-oq-zA-OQ-Z])(\d+)$/g;
  if (!categoryRegex.test(lastSegmentPath)) {
    return null;
  }

  const category = url
    .map(x => x.path)
    .join("/");

  return {
    consumed: url,
    posParams: {
      category: new UrlSegment(category, {}),
    }
  };
}
```

And you can add the matcher to your router configuration:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: productMatcher,
    component: ProductComponent
  },
  {
    matcher: categoryMatcher,
    component: CategoriesComponent
  }
];
```

The order here doesn't matter, because both matchers verify if there's a product in the path to making a decision.

Based on the exposed above, you can do anything you want. The [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma623777526433166?file=src/app/app.module.ts) shows a more interesting scenario, with a lazy-loaded module, as you want. But there's nothing so different from what I discussed above.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Amazing! I wasn't aware of Angular's matcher option, so this is really what I was looking for! However, I've noticed three minor issues with the current solution: 1. If you pass e.g. `-pXXX` as route the `productMatcher` will not handle it (correctly), however the `categoryMatcher` will. It should not be handled by both (404) 2. The route parameters don't include the category path 3. The RegExp should probably be `/([a-zA-z0-9\-]+)(-p)(\d+)$/g` to match everything after the last "/" (prod. name). If you could get this changed, I award the bounty!

Comment: Yeah, once in a while I find myself amazed by something I haven't heard of in the angular ecosystem. The issues are fixed.

Comment: This URL still redirects to the category route: `https://httpsstackoverflowcoma623777526433166.stackblitz.io/shop/et--zubehoer-c16/zubehoer-c48/top-cases--taschen-c63/top-case-32l-rosso-passione-pXXX` even though XXX is not a valid decimal, thus should not apply to either category or product matcher. This route on the other hand doesn't show the category page, even though it's one: `https://httpsstackoverflowcoma623777526433166.stackblitz.io/shop`

Comment: Is there any pattern for categories? It would be more robust if, instead of checking if it isn't a product, to verify that it is a category. For example, may I assume that every path that has its last segment that matches "(-[^p])(\d+)$" (a dash followed by a not-p letter followed by one or more digits) represents a category?

Comment: Everything after /shop is a category page, including /shop itself (no category preselected, lists all products in all categories), except it ends with -p{some digits}, then it's a product page.

Comment: But `top-case-32l-rosso-passione-pXXX` wasn't a category, according to one of your comments above (it should be a 404). I think I can consider a category the following regex for the **last segment in the path**: `/shop$|(-[a-oq-zA-OQ-Z])(\d+)$/g`. So it's the word *shop* or any *dash followed by a letter (not p) followed by one or more digits at the end of the segment*. Take a look at the stackblitz demo to see how it is.